# Does there exist a holomorphic function f defined on U\{0} and maps U\{0} onto U, where U is the open unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

I noticed that since f maps the punctured open unit disc into U, which is bounded, so f is bounded on some punctured neighborhood of 0, hence by Riemann's theorem, we can define f at 0. And similar to proving that the only automorphism of U \{0} is the rotation. I carefully thought about where can 0 be mapped to and found that 0 can only be mapped into U, otherwise f(U) would not be open, contradicting the open mapping theorem as f being nonconstant. Hence if we assumed there exists a holomorphic function f form U\{0} onto U, then there would be two distinct points in U that mapped to the same point in U by f. But I got stuck here, I don't know how to get any other clue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any Blaschke product with two distinct terms (so teemwise product of two distinct disc automorphisms) works since it is a $2$ to $1$ map

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't know how to proceed with your method.

Comment: Look up automorphisms of the unit disc, pick two essentially distinct ones (that are not multiple of one another one) and multiply them pointwise - eg $f(z)=z(2z-1)/(z-2)$ is one such example; since $f(0)=f(1/2)$ it is enough to show $f$ surjective and that can be done directly by showing that the quadratic $f(z)=a$ has at least one root in the unit disc when $a$ is in the unit disc which is trivial since the product of roots has absolute value $|a|$

Comment: Do you mean that f maps U\{0} onto U? But I cannot understand how f work at 0, because 0 is not in the original domain, U\{0}

Comment: $f$ is defined on the unit disc and $f(0)=f(1/2)$ so if we consider the restriction of $f$ to the unit disc minus zero, it has the same image as the original $f$

Comment: But our goal is to map U\{0} onto U, and as you said, we have f(0)=f(1/2), then how to make sure there is some point in U\{0} mapped to 0 by f?

Comment: $1/2$ maps to $0$

Comment: I think I misunderstood how you constructed f. You picked two distinct ones, did it mean two möbius maps? And what is”multiply them pointwise”, shouldn’t it be the composition?

Comment: Just multiply - for example $f(z)=z(2z-1)/(z-2)$ is such using $z$ and $(2z-1)/(z-2)$

Comment: OK I got it. Could you explain why f is surjective more explicitly? I have problem understanding your idea

Comment: Just solve the equation $f(z)=a$ which is a quadratic and the product of the roots is $a$ so if $|a|<1$ there is at least one root in the unit disc

Answer (score -1):

We can first apply the Mobius map g
which switches 0 and 1/2 so that
g(U\{0}) = U{1/2}.
Then apply the function h, h(z)=z^2.
So that h(U\{1/2})=U, because h(g(-1/2))=1/4.
Hence  h∘g maps U\{0} onto U,
as h(g(1/((1/2)^(1/2))))=1/2.
Note that h∘g is holomorphic since both h and g are holomorphic.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will edit this in a more readable fashion when I have enough time.